# I cannot get images in the images folder in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I'm trying to do a memory card game with react. I can't get the photos in the img folder to app.js.

[image]

I wrote the photos in appjs like this.

[image]

I have defined a url for pciture but the pictures are not visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`smurf` is Array, try this:

```js
...
return smurfs.map(smurfData=>(
  <img src={smurfData.pic} alt={smurfData.name}/>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<img src={require(`${url}/${smurf.id}.png`)} alt="smurf" width="100" />
```

- You should be able to display it if the URL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

could you check what your smurf.id holds? can't see it's definition in the code attached. also, seems from the part code that you want to do either smurf.name or smurf.pic?

Separately, this works for me

```
src={require('../images/flex.jpg')}
```

you're probably missing the 'require' if the image path seems correct to you